# Problems with Forward References in FParsec

Tags: reference, f#, forward, fparsec

I'm trying to write a Parser with FParsec to parse nested boolean expressions, for instance:

```
false
true
and(false,true,true,true,true)
or(true,true)
and(or(false,true),and(true,true,true,true))
```

Because my grammar involves mutually recursive definitions, I read [in this article](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/understanding-parser-combinators-4/) that I need `createParserForwardedToRef`

My problem is that once I do it, the F# compiler generates the error `Error FS0037: Duplicate definition of value 'predicateListRef'`

This is a working example to reproduce the error:

```
open FParsec

type Predicate =
    | True
    | False
    | And of Predicate list
    | Or of Predicate list

let leftParen: Parser<_, unit> = skipChar '('
let rightParen: Parser<_, unit> = skipChar ')'
let comma: Parser<_, unit> = skipChar ','
let keywordTrue: Parser<_,unit> = skipString "true" >>% Predicate.True  
let keywordFalse: Parser<_,unit> = skipString "false" >>% Predicate.False  
let keywordAnd: Parser<_,unit> = skipString "and"
let keywordOr: Parser<_,unit> = skipString "or"

////// resolving recursive parsers
let predicateList, predicateListRef = createParserForwardedToRef()

let primePredicate = choice [
    keywordTrue
    keywordFalse
]

let conjunction = (keywordAnd >>. leftParen >>. predicateList) .>> rightParen |>> Predicate.And
let disjunction = (keywordOr >>. leftParen >>. predicateList) .>> rightParen |>> Predicate.Or

let compoundPredicate = choice [
    conjunction
    disjunction
]

let predicate = choice [
    primePredicate
    compoundPredicate
]

let predicateListRef = sepBy1 predicate comma  // the error occurs at this line
```

What am I doing wrong (sorry, I'm not familiar with FParsec, F#, and functional programming)?

Answer (score 1):

Your last line should be

```
predicateListRef.Value <- sepBy1 predicate comma
```

You have bound predicateListRef further up in your code to a reference cell, and now you have to set its value.

Comment: Thank you. Meanwhile, I found what also seems to be another solution "predicateListRef  := sepBy1 predicate comma". Would it be equivalent in F# / FParsec or is it something else?

Comment: Yes, that still works but is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/#reference-cell-operators-deprecated).